# How to reverse items stored in variable before being used in foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a webpage that contains a few ASP.NET panels and JavaScript that is executed when the user clicks a button to expand and collapse the panels. I need to open the panels in the reverse order but using JavaScript reverse() doesn't appear to reverse the order of items stored in components (panels variable).

I have the following JavaScript:

```
function expandCollapsePanels() 
{
    var collapse = $('#<%= lbltogglePanels.ClientID %>').html() == "Collapse all panels";
    var panels = Sys.Application.getComponents(); //adding .reverse() does not work

    for (var i in panels) 
    {
        panels[i].set_Collapsed(collapse);
    }
}
```

How can I modify the code above to do this?

Comment: to you want to reverse the order they open or simple reverse the dom order?

Comment: @meo, I want to reverse the order they open

Comment: If you put an alert() in your loop to tell you the order they are being processed in and the order is as intended, then you might need to put in a delay between each call to .set_Collapsed.

Comment: I tried adding an alert, but it didn't display anything (the code appeared to still execute, however. I added alert(i) in the foreach loop - is that correct?

Comment: @aspdotnetuser could you do console.log( panels ); and tell us what it contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply loop in the opposite direction:

```
for (var i = panels.length-1; i>=0; i--) 
{
  panels[i].set_Collapsed(collapse);
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/de6NF/1/

Answer (score 2):

An easy, but may not be the best, way to do that will be to push the "panels" into an array in the for..in and then call "set_Collapsed" in a for loop using the array.

Comment: If it is already an array, then for..in is not needed and a for loop will work as shown by you. Also, reverse() should work for an array.